# Trick Comcast into thinking I'm loading a lot of pages

Tags: internet, windows-8.1

Comcast has an addon to my server where it will increase my speeds to almost *half* of what I'm paying for instead of the usual quarter for the first 1-2 seconds of loading something new. It's called BURST by Comacast.

I'd like to know how I can make comcast think I'm constantly loading new webpages instead of loading (for example) the same video so I can get closer to what I'm actually paying for.

Comment: Addon to your server or addon to your _service_? Also, are you really only getting 1/4 of what you pay for? I've had comcast and regularly got slightly higher than I was paying for. Make sure you have a DOCSIS 3.0 compliant modem and that you've reset your modem recently (just power cycling is fine). If you're still getting speeds that low, definitely file a support ticket.

Comment: And realize that due to bandwidth delay product, you will not saturate your connection with a single download of a distant resource.

Comment: Have you checked their TOS/AUP? "Tricking" an ISPs systems is usually blanket forbidden and may get you disconnected. (I'm not trying to talk down to you, just ask)

Comment: I don't think this works the way you think it does, e.g. see http://www.dslreports.com/faq/14520. Initiating new connections won't make your current connections faster.

Comment: I suggest you read your service agreement with Comcast. If in fact you are not getting what you paid for, I suggest you take it up with Comcast, rather that resorting to "trickery".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The burst is not a per-connection thing, so making more connections won't have any effect. The burst is applied to the total outbound traffic from your ISP to your connection. Basically, you get a certain number of bytes of traffic before fair share distribution kicks in. When you aren't receiving data, your credits accumulate until you hit that limit. Then when you start transferring data, your deplete those credits and when they hit zero, you begin sharing normally.

Typically, while you are looking at a web page, you aren't transferring anything. So when you click on a link to go to another page, you would typically have the maximum "credits" you can have and get the full burst. But if don't have a low-traffic period, you won't accumulate any credits. It's not looking specifically at what you are exchanging traffic with.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't [ at least not with regular web pages].  It sounds to me like this "Burst" is a sales pitch for QoS management and capping you.   It would most likely work on the tcp stream for each connection, so if you are doing downloads, I'm guessing you would get better performance using torrenting software which makes a lot of connections to lots of places and pieces the file together.

BTW, is "Burst" the same as ["Powerboost"](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/14520) ?  (If so, the description is really, really fits the description of packet shaping a bandwidth pool).

Comment: Yes, I believe it's Powerboost. It is actually a real thing, there's a bump at the start of every graph in all my speedtest results.

Comment: Regular web pages already get the boost. The whole point is to make normal browsing faster, while attempting to cap bulk transfer speed. From personal experience, you're absolutely right that this makes torrents very fast because of the separate connections made for each piece.

Comment: @chipperyman573 - I have no doubt its a real thing.  From my perspective (as someone who used to run ISP's when bandwidth was expensive), its really just a spin on what they need to do to run their network.  Effectively they have set up QoS to allow high bursts on a per [tcp] stream basis, and then slow it down.  If they had enough bandwidth, they would simply not slow you down !!!